# Spring Cloud Config Server-GITLAB SSH Connection

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab, ssh-keys, spring-cloud-config

After going the number of SO threads and blogs and Spring cloud config documentation still, I couldn't find on how I can connect to remote GITLAB repository as I'm getting below error while starting the spring-cloud-config server.

> Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@private_gitlab_repo:project
          search-paths: '{application}'
          skip-ssl-validation: true
          strict-host-key-checking: false
          known-hosts-file: C:\Users\myname\.ssh\known_hosts
```

- spring-boot :2.1.2.RELEASE
- spring-cloud.version: Greenwich.RELEASE
- OS: Windows-7

With the command prompt, I could able to interact with the GITLAB repository. I do have the SSH key generated and added the public key in GITLAB settings. Also, I do not have the option to use username and password to connect to GITLAB.

Any pointers on where I'm missing the configuration or steps?

Answer (score -1):

Found that this is my IntelliJ idea IDE issue and when I try running the same project in command prompt it worked without any issues.